# Can I use sendmail instead of mailx in unattended-upgrades?

Tags: ubuntu, upgrade, sendmail, unattended, mailx

I've configured `unattended-upgrades` for apt to upgrade automatically and setup `sendmail` with a gmail account I made for it. Now I want `unattended-upgrades` to use `sendmail` to send me an email with the logs. However, the manual says it needs to use `mailx` which is annoying to install and just seems unnecessary since `sendmail` works just fine. Also, `mailx` comes with `mailutils` which requires all sorts of unwanted dependencies. I'm running Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Answer (score 0):

The two programs have different interfaces. Tools such as `mailx` will accept text and subject and will generate the message data and headers, taking care of MIME parts and character encodings and such; while the `sendmail` binary expects a complete pre-formatted message instead.

In other words, mailx is a program that generates RFC822 compliant email messages, which is completely different from sendmail (which is a program that delivers provided messages via SMTP). So from the programmer's perspective, no, sendmail doesn't work "just fine" because it doesn't offer the features that mailx does.

However, you do not need to duplicate your configuration, as mailx will itself use sendmail to deliver the message it just generated. (It doesn't require being configured with an SMTP server, and indeed many mailx versions don't even know SMTP at all.)

There are several mailx implementations. If you want a version that is lighter on dependencies, you can install **`heirloom-mailx`** (also sometimes packaged as `nail` or `s-nail`) or even its predecesor the original **`bsd-mailx`**, instead of the GNU mailutils variant.

Comment: Ok thanks for the info. Interestingly, `unattended-upgrades` did end up sending me an email. I'm not sure how it did that but it must have been using sendmail in some capacity. I might have mailx installed but don't know about it? (Running `mail` or `mailx` doesn't work though)

Comment: In that case, it could be that the manual is wrong and unattended-upgrades _may_ have been programmed to handle both interfaces (I mean, it's not actually difficult to generate/format an email message from Python). But did you get the mail from u-u itself, or was it from cron? When cron jobs generate output to stdout, crond always uses sendmail directly.